# Firebase: Can you make the password reset email set the email verified flag?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I noticed that after a user receives a password reset email and resets their password, the email verified flag on the user's account is unchanged. Can this behaviour be changed?

I find this behaviour confusing as if the user changes the password they've obviously confirmed they are in control of the email account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another question might be: if you are in control of the email account and you want to reset the password, does it mean that you are the original user?

i.e. you may be able to do it, is it however a correct behavior? Others will be more useful for the technical aspect but I thought that this might be worth thinking about.